# How do you make a non-modal topmost dialog that is only topmost in regards to the parent form in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, topmost, non-modal

Thinking about this for an About dialog but I'm sure it's applicable in other places (say a find box)

Sorry if this is a dupe, but I couldn't find this or how to articulate the last part about it only being on top of the parent.  How do you make a form that is always on top of the parent form, but is non-modal, but doesn't cover up other apps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this to open your dialog:

```
FindDialog fd = new FindDialog();
fd.Show(this);
```

The key is to assign dialog's owner.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean; Form.ShowDialog is only modal with respect to the parent, not the application, unless the application is single threaded.

For example, I made an app to test this which was organized like the following:

mainform: 
2 buttons, each of which begins a thread that creates a frmDialog1 and calls ShowDialog

frmDialog1:
single button which creates a frmDialog2 and calls ShowDialog on it.

frmDialog2:
does nothing (ie. blank)

when they were all running I could access/drag mainform. I could also do the same with frmDialog1 (both versions) only if I hadn't clicked the button that shows dialog 2.

Comment: "Form.ShowDialog is only modal with respect to the parent, not the application, unless the application is single threaded." Right, but I want it non-modal with respect to the parent, however I still wanted it always on top of the parent.

Comment: Also, you're right that I could start a new thread to display the dialog to not block the main UI, but I try to avoid manual threading if I can help it.  I don't need the dialog result, it's just an About dialog after all, so starting a thread seems overkill.

Comment: As it's your app I'll defer to your wisdom; but a 2 liner Thread whatever = new Thread(methodname); whatever.Start(); is hardly overkill.