# How to start up with 2 forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, authentication, startup

I'm trying to have 2 forms on start up, one is a log in form that can be pushed aside or closed, I just need it to open ontop of my main menu. I've tried this:

```
public partial class MainMenu : Form
{
    public MainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Log_In login = new Log_In();
        login.Show();
        login.Activate();
    }
```

But that open the Log_In form underneith my main menu. How would I go about making it pop up on top of my main menu as soon as the program starts? Thanks!

Comment: @Brian, that will cause the program to terminate when the log in form closes. I just saw the `Load` event, maybe I'll try using that

Comment: @Nathan - You are 100% correct (it has been forever since I have used Winforms).  Deleting the comment.

Comment: maybe you need to look into MdiParent, MdiChild. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984329%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Load event still showed the form underneith :/

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061746/can-not-focus-onto-a-form/14065365#14065365) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Show the form after the previous form has been displayed.  Then it will be shown in front and non-modal so you can move it about while continuing to use the background form..

```
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        Login login = new Login();
        login.Show();
    }
```

Comment: There we go, someone got it! Thanks :D

Comment: Note that if the main form is hidden and then re-shown this will call up the login form again.

Comment: What do you mean by hidden? Like programatically `form.hide()`? Thats no problem for me

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Login login;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Loaded -= MainWindow_Loaded;

            login = new Login();

            login.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is winform, not WPF.  That said, the comparable concept is probably appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're having is that you're showing the login form in the main form constructor.  The main form hasn't yet been shown, but it will be shown at some point in the future.  You need to wait until after the main form has finished being shown to show the login form:

```
public Form1()
{
    EventHandler shownHandler = null;
    shownHandler = (s, args) =>
    {
        Log_In login = new Log_In();
        login.Show();
        Shown -= shownHandler;
    };
    Shown += shownHandler;
}
```

Note that, to prevent the login form from being shown multiple times in the event that you hide and then re-show the login form, you can remove the handler the first time it's called.

Comment: I've already found a working answer, but this might work too. Upvote! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainMenu : Form
{
    public MainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.MainMenu_Shown);
    }
    private void MainMenu_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log_In login = new Log_In();
        login.Show();
        login.Activate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the owner for Form 2 as so:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Form2 login = new Form2();
    login.Show(this);
}
```

[How do you make a non-modal topmost dialog that is only topmost in regards to the parent form in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675105/how-do-you-make-a-non-modal-topmost-dialog-that-is-only-topmost-in-regards-to-th/20129753#20129753)

Comment: Downvoters, please comment, will help the learning process. Thank you